# REST webservice full implementation: server + client

Tags: apache, web-services, centos, restful

I've spent a week reading about RESTful webservice and searching for a fully example to build my project above.
When I reach a fully understanding of the REST webservice, I couldn't find any full implementation for it!

I was wondering why there's a lack in code samples of this great technique.

I want to implement it with PHP and Apache web server and make it fully and has all verbs like this tutorial [part-1][1] , [part-2][2] (see comments for links) saying:

> **The Basics of a RESTful Request**
>
> Every REST request consists of essentially the same basic parts:
>
> - **The URL** – This is the URL we’ll be making a request against (often referred to as a resource).
> - **The Verb** – GET, POST, PUT, or DELETE… there are some others out there, but these are the 4 most common ones.
> - **The Params** – The parameters we’ll be supplying to the API, often referred to as the request body.
> - **Credentials** – Username and password… we’ll cover HTTP Digest auth credentials.
>
> And, of course, we’ll have a few pieces for our response as well:
>
> - **The Response Body** – The actual response body the API gave us.
> - **The Response Status Code** – The HTTP status code the API responded with.
> - **Other Response Info** – We’ll also have some other interesting info in the response.

At first I tried [this sample](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7071-PHP-Implement-REST-based-Web-services.html#files) , but I found later that it doesn't follow REST standard rules.

After digging in the web I found [this example](https://github.com/educoder/pest) but it doesn't give me the server code! Just the client code and processing response.

Do you know any common lib for REST that support both server-side and client-side ? with examples and docs? please give me your suggestions , it's urgent .

Comment: Your links [1] and [2] are broken.

Comment: no , but I'm a new user which not allowed to put more than two links in question . Here they are :
[part1](http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/making-restful-requests-in-php/) [part2](http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/)

Comment: Ok @Nancy Smith.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For server side development I can recommend [Restler](http://luracast.com/products/restler/). I don't know any lib that covers both client and server.

Comment: Actually I think it's a great lib , There's 12 examples with documentation . I'm trying all of them now . Client may be included in examples you know , and thus , your answer may be the ONE I've been looking for ;) Thanks in advance